# Checking if username exists POSTBACK

Tags: php, mysql, xhtml

I want to check using the POSTBACK method i the user exists in mysql table. I studying mysql and i understand it will be removed soon but I cant change at the moment. I want the alert to pop up next to the username text box if it already exists.At the moment it isnt working. I have a similar code for password and password confirmation but i think this differs since i need a query. This is what i have:

```
<?php
$passErr = $pass1Err = "";
$passw = $passw1 = "";
$userErr="";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   if (empty($_POST["password"])) {
     $passErr = "Password is required";
                                  }
if (empty($_POST["passconfirm"])) {
     $pass1Err = "Password confirmation is required";
                                 }
if ($_POST['password']!= $_POST['passconfirm'])
 {
     $passErr = "Passwords must be the same";
     $pass1Err = "Passwords must be the same";

 }

}
else {

if (isset($_REQUEST["submit"]))
{

   if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
   {

     $firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["gname"]);
     $middlename = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["mname"]);
     $lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["surname"]);
     $user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"]);
     $addy = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["address"]);
     $post = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["postcode"]);
     $sta = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["state"]);
     $telephone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["tel"]);
     $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]);
     $systemuser= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["susername"]);

$sql2 = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username= '$user'"; 
 $rs = mysql_query($sql2, $conn) 
 or die ('Problem with query' . mysql_error());

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($rs);

       if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
                     if($num_rows != 0){
                $userErr = "Username already exists";
                                }
                                       }


}
}
mysql_close($conn);
} 
?>
```

this is what i got in the form:

```
<label>Chosen Username:</label> <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php 
echo $userErr;?>"/><span class="error">* <?php echo $userErr;?></span><br />

<label>Password:</label> <input type="password" name="password" value="<?php 
echo $passw;?>"/><span class="error">* <?php echo $passErr;?></span><br />
<br />
<label>Password confirmation:</label> <input type="password" name="passconfirm" value="<?php 
echo $passw1;?>"/><span class="error">* <?php echo $pass1Err;?></span><br />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To acheive what your looking for, instead of using

```
   $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($rs);
   if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
       if($num_rows != 0){
           $userErr = "Username already exists";
        }
    }
```

replace it with

```
   $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($rs);
   if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
       $userErr = "Username field cannot be empty";
   }elseif($num_rows > 0){
           $userErr = "Username already exists";
   }
```

That way if the `Username` field is empty, it will error out. And this will also achieve your goal of checking the database to see if the user exists or not.

Comment: thanks for that but it still does not diplay the error. Im gueessing it has to do with the html side of it: <label>Chosen Username:</label> <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php 
echo $userErr;?>"/><span class="error">* <?php echo $userErr;?></span><br />

Comment: Want to add that could it be that im asking for the password confirm errors first, but i put at else in there so then the program is skipping the user checking?

Answer (score 0):

You need to know if request with username return something so error messsage else do insert new user,

```
 $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username= '$user'"; 
 $rs = mysql_query($sql2, $conn) or die ('Problem with query' . mysql_error());

   if($num_rows=mysql_fetch_array($rs)){ 

         $userErr = "Username already exists";

         // ....
     } else{
        // $SQL = "INSERT INTO users SET ... 
     }
```